# How to use Shadowsocks in my app and proxy the webview of app, and not global proxy

Tags: swift, webview, proxy

I have some websites need to proxy in my webview of my app,
I need the Shadowsocks code which can run, and proxy my web in iOS app.
And not global proxy, just proxy the web in my app, Thanks!

Comment: are you able to make this ?